# WEKA quote parse error

Tags: java, weka

While using java "setOptions" function with the bellow properties I am getting an error : "Quote parse error."...

"weka.classifiers.meta.OneClassClassifier -num \"weka.classifiers.meta.generators.GaussianGenerator -S 1 -M 0.0 -SD 1.0\" -nom \"weka.classifiers.meta.generators.NominalGenerator -S 1\" -trr 0.1 -tcl F&B -cvr 10 -cvf 10.0 -P 0.5 -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging -- -P 100 -S 1 -num-slots 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree -- -M 2 -V 0.001 -N 3 -S 1 -L -1 -I 0.0"

I understand that this is occurring because of error in applying quotes, but I am not sure as to where they should be applied.

I thought of applying them before calling REPTree but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever using a Weka classifier with Java code, use the [weka.core.Utils.splitOptions](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code) method to parse the config string without worrying about quoting and escaping characters.

```
// set your configurations parameters here, e.g., "-S 1"
String options = "whatever configuration you want";

// instantiate the classifier object
REPTree tree = new REPTree();

// parse and set the classifier's configuration
tree.setOptions(Utils.splitOptions(options));
```

Also, remember to provide your current code and to format your question.

Comment: This works only for the first level, not if you have nested commands. The only way I am able to work through my problem is by creating respective objects of all the models I use and add them. Still Thanks.

Comment: In that same page, the authors say that "_using the [OptionsToCode class](https://weka.wikispaces.com/file/detail/OptionsToCode.java) to automatically turn a command line into code is specially handy if the command line contains nested classes that have their own options_". Did you give it a try?

Comment: I didn't but the code looks promising. Thank you very much :)